# Inherit generic type and force the <type>

Tags: java, class, generic-type-argument

Is it possible to inherit generic type and to force in the child class the type received?

Something like:

```
class A<GenericType>{}
class B extends A<GenericType>{}
```

Or:

```
class B <PreciseType> extends A <GenericType>{}
```

But where do I define the GenericType used in B?

Comment: What's wrong with `class B extends A<PreciseType>{}` ?

Comment: Where do I precise the type then ?

Comment: It would be helpful to stick with the normal Java coding conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
class A<T> {}
```

It depends on what you try to do, but both options are possible:

```
class B extends A<SomeType> {};
B bar = new B();
A<SomeType> foo = bar; //this is ok
```

and

```
class B<T> extends A<T>{}; //you could use a name different than T here if you want
B<SomeType> bar = new B<SomeType>();
A<SomeType> foo = bar; //this is ok too
```

But keep in mind that in the first case *SomeType* is an actual class (like `String`) and in the second case *T* is a generic type argument that needs to be instantiated when you declare/create *objects* of type B.

As a piece of advice: using generics in collections is easy and straightforward, but if you want to create your own generic classes you really need to understand them properly. There are a few important gotchas about their variance properties, so read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) carefully and many times to master them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming A is declared as `class A<T> {}` and you want be to be specialised on `String` only for example, you can declare it as `class B extends A<String>`.

Example:

```
public class A<T> {
    public T get() {
        return someT;
    }
}

public class B extends A<String> {
    public String get() {
        return "abcd";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class B extends A<GenericType>{}
```

This is possible. Your `B` class will be a new class that extends generic `A` class with specific class as parameter and `B` will not be a generic class.

```
class B <PreciseType> extends A <GenericType>{}
```

In this case you create a generic class `B` which has generic parameter `PreciseType`. This class `B` extends a specific version of `A`, but `A`'s parameter doesn't depend on `PreciseType`.

If you want to create a generic class that has a parameter which is used in specification of parent class you can use the following:

```
class B <PreciseType> extends A <PreciseType>{}
```

Comment: the second and third cases are incorrect, you cannot use an actual type in the generic arguments declaration of B, only type variables (that can be bounded with existing types though).